# Where do I start looking based on this crash report?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I am still new to crash report analysis and could use some help tracking down my issue. Here's part of the report in question.

```
Incident Identifier: 5D510334-3888-40A6-A7C1-5AE1109BFDD4
CrashReporter Key:   b4cfc1c63d61ef3f17a53e0732f05ad768cad375
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         WxT [1263]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E7B24747-F168-4E23-99F9-89DC23A8531C/WxT.app/WxT
Identifier:      WxT
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-07 21:35:25.723 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000020
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MapKit                          0x318325d2 _contains(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*) + 10
1   MapKit                          0x318325c0 -[MKQuadTrie contains:] + 20
2   MapKit                          0x3184411c -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:] + 264
3   MapKit                          0x3185645e -[MKMapView addAnnotation:] + 46
4   WxT                             0x0009b654 -[RadarViewController dProc2addLocalStormReports] (RadarViewController.m:6234)
5   WxT                             0x00093040 -[RadarViewController download:didFinishWithData:processObject:forStation:] (RadarViewController.m:2519)
6   WxT                             0x000a67b8 -[DownloadManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] (DownloadManager.m:185)
7   Foundation                      0x3436def2 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 14
8   Foundation                      0x342ad9ec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
9   Foundation                      0x342ad908 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
10  CFNetwork                       0x370945dc ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 24
11  CFNetwork                       0x37093cc8 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 52
12  CFNetwork                       0x370bc130 ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 16
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3948b74a CFArrayApplyFunction + 174
14  CFNetwork                       0x370bc58e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
15  CFNetwork                       0x3702015a MultiplexerSource::perform() + 186
16  CoreFoundation                  0x3951a680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
17  CoreFoundation                  0x39519ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
18  CoreFoundation                  0x39518cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3948beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3948bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
21  GraphicsServices                0x378592e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
22  UIKit                           0x326cb2f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
23  WxT                             0x0008c626 main (main.m:14)
24  WxT                             0x0008c5e0 start + 36
```

What I think this is telling me:

(1) A MapKit function is called and is expecting to reference an area in memory that was deallocated.  Thread0, item0: _contains(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*)

(2) My code somehow deallocated this memory when it should not have.

(3) The part of my code that led to the problem is referred to at items 4, 5, and 6 under Thread0

Do I understand that correctly, and where should I go from there?

**Edit:**
After reading the first comments, I tried passing a nil to addAnnotation: to simulate the issue. When deliberately passing nil I get different Exception Types and Codes. Here is the resulting crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 2BC5BEB8-6295-44A1-9235-26AE060C571A
CrashReporter Key:   b4cfc1c63d61ef3f17a53e0732f05ad768cad375
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         WxT Pro [2689]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/3AE2A909-C6E5-421A-BEE9-6DCAFEAE40B6/WxT Pro.app/WxT Pro
Identifier:      WxT Pro
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  debugserver [2687]

Date/Time:       2012-11-09 12:55:11.457 -0600
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3954529e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3343497a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3949d2fa -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 582
3   MapKit                          0x31844166 -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:] + 338
4   MapKit                          0x3185645e -[MKMapView addAnnotation:] + 46
5   WxT Pro                         0x000b055c -[RadarViewController dProc2addLocalStormReports] (RadarViewController.m:6574)
6   WxT Pro                         0x000af31a -[RadarViewController dProc2processLocalStormReportListDownload:] (RadarViewController.m:6234)
7   WxT Pro                         0x000a2bfc -[RadarViewController download:didFinishWithData:processObject:forStation:] (RadarViewController.m:2721)
8   WxT Pro                         0x000c3e36 -[DownloadManager connectionDidFinishLoading:] (DownloadManager.m:185)
9   Foundation                      0x3436def0 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
10  Foundation                      0x342ad9ec -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 196
11  Foundation                      0x342ad908 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
12  CFNetwork                       0x370945da ___delegate_didFinishLoading_block_invoke_0 + 22
13  CFNetwork                       0x37093cc6 ___withDelegateAsync_block_invoke_0 + 50
14  CFNetwork                       0x370bc12e ___performAsync_block_invoke_068 + 14
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3948b748 CFArrayApplyFunction + 172
16  CFNetwork                       0x370bc58e RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 70
17  CFNetwork                       0x37020158 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 184
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3951a67e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
19  CoreFoundation                  0x39519f7a __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
20  CoreFoundation                  0x39518cb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3948beb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3948bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
23  GraphicsServices                0x378592e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
24  UIKit                           0x326cb2f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
25  WxT Pro                         0x00096f36 main (main.m:14)
26  WxT Pro                         0x00096edc start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3123b350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x345ca11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3460696e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37726d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37723ff4 _ZL17default_terminatev + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33434a74 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37724078 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37724110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37725594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334349cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3948bf1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3948bd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x378592e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x326cb2f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  WxT Pro                         0x00096f36 main (main.m:14)
15  WxT Pro                         0x00096edc start + 36
```

So, I assume I am not passing nil in production. But, does that mean that my pointer is pointing to memory that has been rewritten and no longer represents the original data?

Comment: Looking at the address (`0x20`) it seems more like you are passing `nil` to `addAnnotation:` or you are working with a `nil` value and pass an offset to it to `addAnnotation:`

Comment: You should add an exception break point to your project (if you haven't already), and see if this will point you to the offending line of code.

Comment: @rdelmar Sadly, this problem is very intermittent. I can add the break point, but cannot recreate the problem.

Comment: @JustSid thanks. I tried passing nil to simulate the error, but the report shows different exceptions when I do that (see my edits in the original question). I guess I am not certain what you mean by "or you are working with a nil value and pass an offset to it to addAnnotation:". How would I verify/disprove that?

Comment: Perhaps the map view has been dealloced?

Comment: Are you using ARC?  I would look around RadarViewController.m:6234 and see if you are passing an argument that you may have overreleased previously.

Comment: @JoeHankin no ARC. If I analyze my code, and it does not report any memory issues, does that imply that I could not have over-released, or can that slip through the analysis?

Comment: It can definitely slip through the analysis -- static analysis is far from foolproof.  Go through your code with a fine-toothed comb and look for anywhere you may have overreleased.  You should also turn on zombie objects (go to Edit Scheme->Diagnostics->Enable Zombie Objects) so that when it crashes next time, the logs will tell you what class of object was overreleased.

Comment: It also looks like your problem is originating with a delegate callback, `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, so you should be very careful that you haven't prematurely released a request object or some such that owns whatever it is you're using in your annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You may have already solved this issue, but I was getting the same crash report and realized that I was trying to add an annotation at an invalid coordinate.  My data source (an API that returns JSON) was giving me an invalid latitude value.

I altered this code:

```
    //add the Station object to the array
    [stations addObject:tempStation]; // <--(this eventually calls [MKMapView addAnnotation:])
```

...into this, adding a safeguard:

```
    if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(tempStation.coordinate))
    {
        //add the Station object to the array if its coordinate is valid
        [stations addObject:tempStation];
    }
    else
    {
        //otherwise just log an error and go to the next station
        NSLog("Invalid station coordinate: stationID %d, %@, coord %f, %f", tempStation.stationID, tempStation.name, tempStation.latitude, tempStation.longitude);
    }
```

I got this log the next time I ran my code:

```
Invalid station coordinate: stationID 311, 14th St & Colorado Ave NW, coord -1345.707008, -77.032947
```

The invalid data was ignored and the crashing stopped.